# Remove multiple occurences of unknown text between tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, text-parsing

I want to use mySQL, or PHP (if too tough in SQL), to get rid of all occurrences of any text between certain strings/tags.
I have a database field that looks like the following:

```
<chrd>F                              Gm<br><indx>Here's a little song I wrote   You might want to sing it note for note...<br><chrd>       Bb    C     F<br><text>Don't Worry    Be Happy<br><text>In every life we have some trouble  When you worry you make it double...<br><text>Don't Worry Be Happy
```

I want to remove the text between the tags `<chrd>` and `<br>` (tags included or not). I have tried

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(text, '<chrd>', -1), '<br>', 1),'') FROM songs;
```

but returns only the last occurrence (       `Bb    C     F`). How can I select all occurrences?

Also, the above returns all the text if there is a song with no chords. I would like it to return an empty string.

After I get rid of the chords, I will do multiple `REPLACE` to remove all the tags, so that I will be left with only the plain text and the lyrics. (This is OK, I can do)

*Note: I don't know about regular expressions and procedures*

Comment: *"occurrences of any text"* do you mean occurrences of any word ? or char ?

Comment: "occurrences of any string", if you prefer. Not a single character, not a word, as you see in the example.

Answer (score 0):

As the `<chrd>` tags have no closing tags in your string, a dom parser will be no use.

There are ways to do this using a regular expression or splitting strings, but I have to warn you they could be unreliable. That said, the following works, using a regular expression:

```
$string="
<chrd>F                              Gm<br><indx>Here's a little song I wrote   You might want to sing it note for note...<br><chrd>       Bb    C     F<br><text>Don't Worry    Be Happy<br><text>In every life we have some trouble  When you worry you make it double...<br><text>Don't Worry Be Happy";

$regex='/\<chrd\>.*?\<br\>/';
$result = preg_replace($regex,'',$string);
echo $result;
```

The regex breakdown:

```
\<chrd\>  : search for <chrd> tag
.*?       : any charachter 0 to unlimited times, as few as possible
\<br\>    : untill it hits <br> (included)
```

[With a fiddle](https://onlinephp.io/c/bc0da)

Comment: Nice! But, when I try this regex in MySQL it doesn't work (while others like [a-z] work).

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'/\<chrd\>.*?\<br\>/','') FROM songs;` gives me the whole text unchanged

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex in Mysql. It can be incredably slow. Unless you have to search for the pattern in the database, let PHP handle the string replacement.

Comment: I managed to make the regex work, with a different syntax. Then, adding two more REPLACE my SQL query became:
`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'(\<chrd\>)(.*?)(\<br\>)',''),'<br>','\n'),'(<)(.*?)(>)','') FROM songs;`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a19f06cfc24d9515164579e6b5e25e7d

Thank you @Michel, I wish I could up-vote your reply but I cannot (yet)